# Does "related" consider who asked and answered, or only tags and content?

Tags: support, related-questions

On some sites, I am occasionally surprised by the related questions linked beside a question. I expect to see questions with the same tags. I expect to see questions with the same words whether those words are tags or not. But sometimes the only correlation I can see is that I answered both questions.

Is this me spotting a pattern (I remember that question! I answered it!) that isn't there, or does the Related algorithm use us as human pattern-matchers and take into account that any two questions answered by the same person have a chance of being related?